# How to decrease project folder size for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've migrated a project from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio`.

On `Eclipse`, the project had a size of about `400MB`.

After migrating to `Android Studio`, the project blew up to `1.8GB`.

How can I decrease the size of the project?

Are there any temp files that do not get automatically deleted?

Comment: Not writing this as an answer, as it is speculation: I imagine a lot of those files are pre-prepared files to speed up building your project. If you have multiple flavours, that data could be multiplied. Another reason, if you import library projects, those are now included in your project folder, instead of being spread out.

Answer (score 3):

Simply open a command line in your project’s root folder and run the following command:

```
gradlew clean
```

Notice that you get a bit of an unexpected message:

> “BUILD SUCCESSFUL.”

This simply indicates that it has gone through and successfully cleaned out the intermediate files.